# Why my XBMC library is empty?

Tags: network-shares, kodi

I installed XBMC on my MacBook and Android mobile phone, turned upnp share on.I added source, but both music library and video library are empty.

Can you tell me how to add files to library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you scanned them?

List of ways to scan movies into the Video library:

- Choose automatic scan when you set the content for the source.
- Select the item in file view and either press I on the keyboard, or
  bring up the contextual menu (press C) and select "Movie information"
  or "TV show information"
- If the file is already scanned in, you can also use the info screen
  to refresh/update that entry in the library.
- You can select the share/folder that your videos are in and choose
  "Scan for new content" from the contextual menu (press C), which
  scans all files in that share/folder.
- In Library view you can choose "Update library" from the contextual 
  menu (press C).   Have XBMC scan for new items upon start up by going
  to  Settings -> Video -> Library ->
- Update library on startup
- Add-on:XBMC Library Auto Update can be used to schedule automatic
  updates to the library.
- Add-on:Library watchdog can be used to watch local folders (or
  locally mounted network shares) for new files to trigger library
  updates.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44214041/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-08%20at%2011.25.29%20AM.png no "scan item to library" here, I clicked update, but no changes.

Comment: This might help http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Adding_videos_to_the_library/Setting_content_and_scanning#Scanning_and_updating_files